# How to navigate from portlet to portlet

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

My question is how can I go from one portlet to another.

My scenario is this:

The user can view a specific portlet's view.jsp. When he clicks on a button then the page will show the view.jsp of another portlet. Maybe this is called portlet redirection, but I have no idea how to implement this.

Maybe one solution could be different jsp files in the same portlet but I want to navigate through portlets not the jsps.

It would be useful if someone could provide me a sample of code or a reference to a literature that will help me find out how to implement this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer to below link hope it will help

http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/8408006

or else you can create like this.

```
LiferayPortletURL anotherPortletURL = PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(request,portletName, 
plid, PortletRequest.RENDER_PHASE);
```

Comment: This link is not accessible. Thank you although.

Comment: try again http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/8408006

Comment: np.glad i could help :)